# Skip only first line in the first iteration

Tags: r, loops

I am trying to skip only one command or line in the 1st iteration inside a loop, and then, continue working:

I did it with success, but I wonder if exist some way to do this task more simple.

I only want omit the first line in the first iteration, I have multiple lines:

```
      for(n in 1:5) {
               if(n == 1)   {
                    # I wanna omit this line below, my real script not have the line below
                    #print(paste0("This is my ",n, " iteration, continue running my script"))
           
                    print(n)
                    print("I only wanna omit the first line  in the beginning of loop, then continue my work")

                    }else{

                    print(paste0("This is my ",n, " iteration, continue running my script"))
                    print("I only wanna omit the first line  in the beginning of loop, then continue my work")
                    }
             }

             [1] 1
             [1] "I only wanna omit the first line  in the beginning of loop, then continue my work"
             [1] "This is my 2 iteration, continue running my script"
             [1] "I only wanna omit the first line  in the beginning of loop, then continue my work"
             [1] "This is my 3 iteration, continue running my script"
             [1] "I only wanna omit the first line  in the beginning of loop, then continue my work"
             [1] "This is my 4 iteration, continue running my script"
             [1] "I only wanna omit the first line  in the beginning of loop, then continue my work"
             [1] "This is my 5 iteration, continue running my script"
             [1] "I only wanna omit the first line  in the beginning of loop, then continue my work"
```

I did try:

```
    for(n in 1:5) {

            if(n==1)  
            print(paste0("I only wanna omit the first line  in the beginning of loop, then continue my work")) 

            print(paste0("This is my ",n, " iteration, continue running my script"))  ;next

    }
```

but not work:

```
    [1] "I only wanna omit the first line  in the beginning of loop, then continue my work"
    [1] "This is my 1 iteration, continue running my script"
    [1] "This is my 2 iteration, continue running my script"
    [1] "This is my 3 iteration, continue running my script"
    [1] "This is my 4 iteration, continue running my script"
    [1] "This is my 5 iteration, continue running my script"
```

Another try:

```
    for(n in 1:5) {

          if(n==1)  
          print(paste0("I only wanna omit the first line  in the beginning of loop, then continue my work")) ;next
          print(paste0("This is my ",n, " iteration, continue running my script"))  

    } 

  [1] "I only wanna omit the first line  in the beginning of loop, then continue my work"
```

Try 3:

```
    for(n in 1:5) {
           if(n == 1)   {
                print("I wanna skip this line in first iteration")
                print(n)
                print("I only wanna omit the first line  in the beginning of loop, then continue my work")
               
                print("I dont wanna skip this line in first iteration")
                print(n)
                print(paste0("This is my ",n, " iteration, continue running my script"))
               }  ;next
         }

             [1] "I wanna skip this line in first iteration"
             [1] 1
             [1] "I only wanna omit the first line  in the beginning of loop, then continue my work"
             [1] "I dont wanna skip this line in first iteration"
             [1] 1
             [1] "This is my 1 iteration, continue running my script"
```

Comment: Why not just `for (n in 2:5) …`? — That said, what are you iterating over here? there might be a better solution but this depends entirely on what your loop is actually doing.

Comment: @Adam yes, I want this

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph  If I  use: for (n in 2:5), I omit all the first iteration but I only want omit the first line in the first iteration.

Comment: Think of it not as skipping the first if (n == 1) but rather running the first if (n > 1). Should be a bit less logic. `if (n > 1) {... stuff}` and then you can have the rest of the code as normal without having to be inside an else statement.

Comment: @adam, your are right. This work for me. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Adam comment because that help me to get the right answer, was more easy that I thought:

```
        for(n in 1:5) {
              if(n > 1)
              print("I wanna skip this line in first iteration")  
                 print(n)
                 print("I only wanna omit the first line  in the beginning of loop, then continue my work")
        
                 print("I dont wanna skip this line in first iteration")
                 print(n)
                 print(paste0("This is my ",n, " iteration, continue running my script")) 
       
  } 

  [1] 1
  [1] "I only wanna omit the first line  in the beginning of loop, then continue my work"
  [1] "I dont wanna skip this line in first iteration"
  [1] 1
  [1] "This is my 1 iteration, continue running my script"
  [1] "I wanna skip this line in first iteration"
  [1] 2
  [1] "I only wanna omit the first line  in the beginning of loop, then continue my work"
  [1] "I dont wanna skip this line in first iteration"
  [1] 2
  [1] "This is my 2 iteration, continue running my script"
  [1] "I wanna skip this line in first iteration"
  [1] 3
  [1] "I only wanna omit the first line  in the beginning of loop, then continue my work"
  [1] "I dont wanna skip this line in first iteration"
  [1] 3
  [1] "This is my 3 iteration, continue running my script"
  [1] "I wanna skip this line in first iteration"
  [1] 4
  [1] "I only wanna omit the first line  in the beginning of loop, then continue my work"
  [1] "I dont wanna skip this line in first iteration"
  [1] 4
  [1] "This is my 4 iteration, continue running my script"
  [1] "I wanna skip this line in first iteration"
  [1] 5
  [1] "I only wanna omit the first line  in the beginning of loop, then continue my work"
  [1] "I dont wanna skip this line in first iteration"
  [1] 5
  [1] "This is my 5 iteration, continue running my script"
```